# Referer null help me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, referer

Good morning guys. I'm having the following problem. I created an override method to validate referer:

```
public class VerifyOutUrlReferer : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            {"controller", "Validate"},
                            {"action", "Referer"},
                            {"code", 123ER}
                        });
        }
    }
}

[VerifyOutUrlReferer]
public ActionResult GeneralError(string errorCode)
{
    return View();
}
```

and add it on top of the method...

I try to call this method by screen controller that validates 404 error, so that does not always redirects to her because the referer is empty. Could someone help me how I can call this screen by controllers.